# create foreign key without a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, foreign-keys, primary-key, key

Why is it necessary to have a primary key on a column of one table to which a column of the other table having foreign key references.

```
create table D(Did int)
create table E(Eid int foreign key references D(Did))
```

The above query gives error:

```
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'D' that match
the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__E__Eid__79C80F94'.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy. If you have 2 values the same in the parent table, how do you know which one to associate child rows to?
 One side of foreign key must be unambiguous

The requirement is also "unique key", not just a primary key which of course unique

Comment: But if you want to implement a "at least one" constraint then by definition you don't want that constraint to refer to just one row. You haven't explained why such constraints aren't supported and I don't believe there is any good reason. It's just a silly limitation that is one example of how poor SQL's support for integrity constraints is.

Answer (score 18):

Very good question. There is no fundamental reason why a referential constraint shouldn't reference something other than a candidate key. There is even a name for such constraints: Inclusion Dependencies. A foreign key is just a type of inclusion dependency where the target of the constraint happens to be a candidate key.

Unfortunately SQL doesn't provide good support for inclusion dependencies or even for referential constraints generally. SQL limits its so-called FOREIGN KEY constraints to referencing the columns of a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint (not necessarily a candidate key though).

So what you have come up against is really a dubious limitation of SQL. It doesn't mean you are doing anything very wrong.

Comment: And how does this help *in real life*. However good or bad SQL is, you still need to reference a unique constraint in the parent table. SO -1 for an utterly useless answer to OP's question: you said "SQL is broke". Jolly good.

Comment: I think I'm the only person who answered the question, which was "Why?". I think it's important to point out that this is a software limitation and not give the impression that the OP was doing something wrong. The question wasn't how to workaround the error but to explain why it occurred.

Comment: there is only one reaosn: ALL relational cauculus are based on the fact that a foreign key maps to a unique column.

Comment: @Nei: The TRC and DRC don't rely on the presence or absence of referential constraints - even ones that reference a "unique column" [sic]. Maybe you could clarify or rewrite your comment to explain better what you mean.

Comment: @sqlvogel:
Very good point about `Inclusion Dependencies`. Never knew that! +1

Comment: +1 for the clear explanation! As a side note, if you have one table that has a composite key (i.e, more than one primary key) and you try to reference just one of those key in another keys (instead of the set of keys/composite key) you will get the same error. In such a case, try creating unique index on the column that needs to be referenced in another table. Here's a link: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-1776.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I thinks the PK it's used internally so the sql server knows on what line to operate on. If you don't have a PK and put the same values on two different rows then the sql server will have trouble processing the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Without a foreign key on D, records in E have no way of knowing, which record is referenced.

Comment: D must have a primary key or unique column, every foreign key references a column that exists in another table, so E has the foreign key actually.

Comment: That is what I wrote. Without a primary key in D, the (foreign-key) records in E do not know, which (primary-key) in D is referenced. Please take back your down-vote. Thank you.