# Entity Framework - Cannot create association

Tags: entity-framework

My SQL database has only 3 tables. 1 is called Country, another is called CountryAlias and the last is Person.

[image]

The relation between tblCounty and tblCountyAlias is 1 to many using the [Country] column in both as the relating column. And then the relation between tblCountry and Person is the same. This example should be fairly textbook.

The problem I have is, it appears that EF wants me to only make associations via the Primary Key (or should I call it the Entity Key). So, my questions are:

1) Does EF only want me to make associations where at least one side of the entity uses the Entity Key

2) Is the Entity Key the same as a primary key (ie, is it safe to remove it from ID and make Country the Entity Key)?

3) Am I fighting the way EF wants to work. Learning WPF means fighting will only result in much pain and failure but I'm not sure if this also applies to EF?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you connect the tables using tblCountry.Id?

Comment: Simply because the ID currently is only there to appease SQL, it's of no real value to my design. However, after reading further I've realised you can't do this (at least not easily) with FK, and as such, I will update so it can be using ID's - it just feels like I'm being forced where as Linq To Sql or even old ADO.Net wouldn't have this issue (I guess this is the pro's and cons of each technology)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you haven't specified which type of Entity Framework you use, but from the context (Entity Key) I guess you are using most likely the Code First type (or maybe Model first)

To make your association work, this is how your model should look like:
[image]

As you can see, it doesn't violate any rules of the Entity Framework to use string type primary keys. (I've included an Id in the Person table, because a person's name might not be unique)

**The answers** based on my experience are:

1) When you create a foreign key in MSSQL with 1 to many, then the first side's (tblCountry in this case) column(s) has to be unique. See [create foreign key without a primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442785/create-foreign-key-without-a-primary-key) 
So basically it doesn't have to be primary key, but it is much easier to use a primary key. But this primary key can be mapped to a string property, or to multiple properties as well (see composite primary keys)

2) Yes, it is the same and I presume the Country column is mapped to a string property which can be unique, so it is perfectly safe to use it as an Entity Key.

3) No you are not fighting the ways and even if you were I think one should always fight a bit with an API to know its limits and characteristics.

I hope this helps!

By the way, when you create a new entity in your model (right click in your model and Add New option) you can choose whatever Entity Key you want, like this:

[image]