# visual studio/ microsoft sql error for relational keys

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

```
CREATE TABLE TBLUSER_INFO
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)not null PRIMARY KEY,
LNAME VARCHAR(50)not null,
FNAME VARCHAR(50)not null,
MNAME VARCHAR (50)not null,
ADDRESS VARCHAR(50)not null,
AGE INT not null,
GENDER VARCHAR(10)not null,
CONTACTNO varchar(50) not null, 
BIRTHDATE datetime
);


CREATE TABLE TBLUSER_ACCOUNT
(
ID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TBLUSER_INFO(ID) ,
USERNAME VARCHAR(50)not null,
USERPASS NVARCHAR(50)not null,
SECURITYQUESTION VARCHAR(max)not null,
SECURITYANSWER VARCHAR(50)not null
);
```

the error is this

```
DBML1011: The Type element 'TBLUSER_ACCOUNT' contains the Association element 'TBLUSER_INFO_TBLUSER_ACCOUNT' but does not have a primary key.  No code will be generated for the association.
```

---

when I run my system in visual, this will be the output
[my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWkyQ.png)

PLS HELP ME FOR MY PROJECT. IM DESPERATE

Comment: its your problem : 'TBLUSER_INFO_TBLUSER_ACCOUNT' but does not have a primary key.'

Comment: please elaborate. beginner here hehe

Comment: DBML1062: The Type attribute 'TBLUSER_ACCOUNT' of the Association element 'TBLUSER_INFO_TBLUSER_ACCOUNT' of the Type element 'TBLUSER_INFO' does not have a primary key.  No code will be generated for the association

Answer (score 1):

`SQL SERVER` requires to have a primary key in your table before you declare any foreign keys.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442785/create-foreign-key-without-a-primary-key) you can see why.

Comment: what will be my primary key for tbluseraccount table? pls help me

Comment: DBML1062: The Type attribute 'TBLUSER_ACCOUNT' of the Association element 'TBLUSER_INFO_TBLUSER_ACCOUNT' of the Type element 'TBLUSER_INFO' does not have a primary key.  No code will be generated for the association

Answer (score 0):

In your `TBLUSER_ACCOUNT` need to add `primary key` ID and fkey with `TBLUSER_INFO` id, like this.

```
 CREATE TABLE TBLUSER_INFO
    (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)not null PRIMARY KEY,
    LNAME VARCHAR(50)not null,
    FNAME VARCHAR(50)not null,
    MNAME VARCHAR (50)not null,
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(50)not null,
    AGE INT not null,
    GENDER VARCHAR(10)not null,
    CONTACTNO varchar(50) not null, 
    BIRTHDATE datetime
    );

    CREATE TABLE TBLUSER_ACCOUNT
    (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) not null PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_TBLUSER_INFO INT,
    USERNAME VARCHAR(50)not null,
    USERPASS NVARCHAR(50)not null,
    SECURITYQUESTION VARCHAR(4000) not null,
    SECURITYANSWER VARCHAR(50)not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_TBLUSER_INFO) REFERENCES TBLUSER_INFO(ID)
    );
```

Comment: Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Foreign key 'ID_TBLUSER_INFO' references invalid column 'ID_TBLUSER_INFO' in referencing table 'TBLUSER_ACCOUNT'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: aye bro can u look at the picture below my question. the name is my system. what is the possible solution for my datagrid. i think i am having a problem in my row/column

Comment: and also bro why is my id is not displaying on the datagrid. i tried to understand but i think its logical error or sumthin

Comment: show in your question how you get data from DB and how you bind it to GridView

Comment: pls reply asap bec we have a debugging and the deadline for this is today. pls help me

Comment: what bro? i cant understand you

Comment: table.ID = int.Parse(txtID.Text);
                table.FNAME = txtFname.Text;
                table.LNAME = txtLname.Text;
                table.MNAME = txtMname.Text;
                table.ADDRESS = txtAddress.Text;
                table.AGE = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);
                table.GENDER = cmbGender.Text;
                table.CONTACTNO = txtContact.Text;
                table.BIRTHDATE = dtpBirthdate.Value;

Comment: qwe.USERNAME = txtUser.Text;
                qwe.USERPASS = txtPass.Text;
                qwe.SECURITYQUESTION = cmbQ.Text;
                qwe.SECURITYANSWER = txtA.Text;
                repositories.Add(table,qwe);
                MessageBox.Show("Information Added");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = repositories.View();

Comment: Maybe get some basic, i haleped you with your problem with DB script.

Comment: what basic bro. pls elaborate bec i cant understand well

Comment: in your own opinion bro. is it in db or visual?

Comment: the problem for my system\

Comment: Db is ok now. You need to correct download your data.